# Why do browsers trust Cloudflare shared SSL certificate?

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, cloudflare

So I chose to use Cloudflare's shared SSL certificate with CDN, now the website I sign up for has this certificate shown in the browser:

[image: SSL Certificate]

The "issued to" domain is not my domain, this caused a problem:

**The https post API of my program thinks my website does not have a valid certificate**

However, when I open up my site with Chrome browser, the secured icon shows up:

[image: https valid icon]

It seems that the browser thinks the Cloudflare shared certificate is OK,

**while the "issued to" domain is clearly not my domain**

So the question is:

> Why does the browser trust the shared SSL certificate with "issued to" not matching my domain, while the WebRequest from a C# program does not trust?

Comment: The CDN is not your domain name.

Comment: I know, but why does the browser trust a "not-matching domain name SSL"?

Comment: Certificates must match the domain name of the request, not the originating site.

Comment: I wonder how this is a programming question related to [tag:c#]...

Comment: But it doesn't match the request, my request is mysite.com, certificate says "sn???.cloudflaressl.com", what is the originating site?

Comment: What request are you seeing that certificate from?

Comment: Check for Subject Alternate Names.

Comment: From Chrome and C# (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest. OK, I feel dumb, I never knew that field existed, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out there is a "Subject Alternate Names" field in the certificate details, which allows browsers to trust certificate with non "issued to" domain, big thanks to @SLaks.

The reason why it didn't work on my C# api access is that Unity does not support ECDH(Elliptic-curve Diffie–Hellman) for HTTPS, and Cloudflare only supports ECDH.

So, the HTTPS api to my server through Cloudflare is working for Chrome, but not working for Unity. I searched around and found it does not work for some versions of Monodevelop lineup and Xiamarin as well.
[Bug](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26658)

Comment: You are using the Free Plan, upgrade to Pro plan then, the HTTPS will be supported everywhere. https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/203041594-Cloudflare-SSL-cipher-browser-and-protocol-support